# Certificates requested through Amazon ACM are stuck in "Pending validation"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-acm

I'm trying to add a certificate to a domain name through Amazon ACM and it's not working. I mean, I was able to add the certificate and I opted to use DNS validation but it's still showing up as "Pending validation" and that was a few hours ago.

I added the DNS entries *after* I requested the certs so is there a way I can just tell AWS to recheck for the DNS entries?

Answer (score 1):

AWS will periodically check the DNS entries.  In the past I've done exactly as you have, and found checking back, after 5-10 minutes is enough.

If after re-checking the console, and you still aren't validating properly, check using an external tool if the records are public.

There are a number of reasons why DNS changes could take a while to make it to AWS, but a few hours is longer than I would expect.  That implies the real result is a misconfiguration.